# Disabling Status Bar Pull Down - Difference in API Versions?

Tags: android, statusbar

I have been trying to prevent the status bar from being pulled down within my app for a long time now.

I have managed to do this on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, and it works fine! Even when the phone is restarted it works again.

However when I tested this on my Samsung Galaxy S6, this does not work. The status bar pulls down and stays down when pulled down fully.

I am guessing this is an issue with the difference in API versions?

If anyone has had any similar issues with this then please let me know if you found a solution.

Here is the code I am using for the prevention of the status bar pull down. You will be able to see that the bar pulls down and then closes instantly, this stops users being able to interact with it:

```
// To keep track of activity's window focus
boolean currentFocus;

// To keep track of activity's foreground/background status
boolean isPaused;

Handler collapseNotificationHandler;

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    currentFocus = hasFocus;

    if (!hasFocus) {

        // Method that handles loss of window focus
        collapseNow();
    }
}

public void collapseNow() {

    // Initialize 'collapseNotificationHandler'
    if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
        collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();
    }

    // If window focus has been lost && activity is not in a paused state
    // Its a valid check because showing of notification panel
    // steals the focus from current activity's window, but does not
    // 'pause' the activity
    if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {

        // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
        collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'

                Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                try {
                    statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Method collapseStatusBar = null;

                try {

                    // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                    // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager .getMethod("collapsePanels");
                    } else {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager .getMethod("collapse");
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

                try {
                    collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Check if the window focus has been returned
                // If it hasn't been returned, post this Runnable again
                // Currently, the delay is 100 ms. You can change this
                // value to suit your needs.
                if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {
                    collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 1L);
                }

            }
        }, 1L);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you want angry users? Or why do you need this functionality?

Comment: Hi Tim, no definitely not angry users. The purpose of the app is to run on the device with no functionality to anything else on the unit.Just the app I am creating. This is a task I have been given by my company, and no I do not work in app development, this is all brand new to me and our company.

Comment: this is not an uncommon requirement, especially for company owned devices and such. Check out kiosk mode for example. You don't have to do all of this disabling yourself

Comment: Hi Tim, I have been looking into Kiosk mode, and there are many apps out there that do exactly what we need. But the few I have looked into are all license based, and would cost a fortune on ongoing costs for our customers. This is why I am looking to do this myself.

Comment: Does anyone have any information on this? - Thanks in advance.